# C++ change value to an element of an int vector in a structure data

Tags: c++

I have a structure data in c++:

```
struct Items
{
    string name;  // car, bike
    int quantity; // 1  , 10
};
```

I must modify an assigned vector that contains all the data:

```
vector<Items> vectorName;
```

(This vector must be used in the code and I want to know how to modify it!!!)

Let's say now the quantity of car is = 1.
How can I add one unity of item car, so that my vector has car = 2 ?

I tried with a loop but it works only inside the loop, if fact if I want to add another car in two different times (add 1 car [so car = 2], add 1 car so [car = 3]), it starts back from car = 1 (so car = 2).

Example of my loop:

```
for (auto& i : vectorName)

    if (i.name == "car") {

        i.quantity += 1;

    }
```

Comment: So you want to store multiple `Item` objects in the vector with the same name?

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a map of enum to quantity.

Comment: I have already stored all items name and quantity, I just want to add quantities to items.

Comment: _it starts back from car = 1_ that's not true. The loop changes the vector elements. Do you copy the vector?

Answer (score 4):

Consider refactoring to

```
std::map<std::string/*name*/, unsigned/*quantity*/> items;
```

Then to increase the quantity of, say `"car"` by 1 you could write

```
++items["car"];
```

The absolutely beautifully designed `std::map` will *automatically* create an appropriate entry if `foo` is not yet in the container (a curiousity of the `[]` operator of the `std::map`), furthermore with the value zero-initialised to 0.

Finally, if you wanted to output your inventory, you could use something on the lines of

```
for (const auto& it : items){
    std::cout << "name " << it.first << " quantity " << it.second << '\n';
}
```

This will output the items lexographically. The approaches used this answer adds to the conjecture, in my mind at least, that a language more expressive than C++ is yet to emerge.

Comment: Not my answer, sorry, I must use my vector.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of an enum is to give a string representation of integers in the code.

```
enum ObjectType {
    Car,
    Bike
    Bus
};
```

In this case, Car will be replaced with the integer value 0; Bike 1; Bus 2.

The concept of a map is to allow a single key to have a single value.
Thus combining them:

```
std::map<ObjectType, int> myThings;
myThings[Car] += 2;
```

Which will ensure that you only ever have a single Car (thus preventing your accidental resets to 0) and remove your for loop, since the loop us is done for you already by the library.

If you really want to keep your vector then you will not be able to trivially add a new item every time; but locate the old entry if it exists and amend that.

Comment: _"The concept of an enum is to give a string representation of integers."_ That's a very misleading description. There are no strings here, just an alphanumeric identifier. It can't be printed or otherwise used like a string; it's just a friendlier representation for an integer that the compiler and the compiler alone knows about

Comment: This works well so long as the population of things you want to add to the container is known at compilation time. If not, then you'll be doing a lot of production releases.

Comment: Yes, but I need to use my vector for other things, so must keep it, can't use enum.